# Why doesn't it sets the $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, mysqli

My script doesn't saves the value into a $_SESSION, how is that possible?

Whenever my users login, i try to place their username into a session.
My only problem is when i use `var_dump($_SESSION['user_name']);` to debug and reveal the current value on the end page, i just keep receiving `NULL`.
Could someone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
    <? php
   include_once('../db/config.php');
  session_start();
  $error = '';
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if (empty($_POST['isamp_username']) || empty($_POST['isamp_password'])) {
          $error = "Username or Password is invalid!";
      } else {
          $isamp = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

          $username = stripslashes($username);
          $password = stripslashes($password);
          $username = $isamp - > real_escape_string($username);
          $password = $isamp - > real_escape_string($password);

          $username = $_POST['isamp_username'];
          $nopassword = $_POST['isamp_password'];
          $password_hash = hash('whirlpool', $nopassword);
          $password = strtoupper($password_hash); // <- Also for the Register!




          $sql = "select * from users where password='$password' AND username='$username'";
          $result = $isamp - > query($sql) or trigger_error($isamp - > error." [$sql]"); /* i have added the suggestion from MY Common Sence */
          if ($result - > num_rows == 1) {
              $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
              header("Location: ../../index.php");
          } else {
              $error = "Username or Password is invalid!";
          }
          $isamp - > close();
      }
  } ?>
```

My HTML:

```
    <?php
    include('login.php');
    ?>

<h2>iSAMP</h2>
<hr/>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Username  :</label>
<input type="text" name="isamp_username" id="name" placeholder="Username"/><br /><br />
<label>Password  :</label>
<input type="password" name="isamp_password" id="isamp_password" placeholder="*******"/><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Login " name="submit"/><br />
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
```

Comment: did you try  echo $username

Comment: Are you sure that your `_POST` requests are correctly set? both on the login page and from the form? All inputs have a name etc

Comment: @zod ofcourse, otherways i wouldnt even be able to get a valid answer from the database. It's a login.

Comment: @DarylGill Yes everything is good, otherwise i wouldn't be able to login and access that page. Otherways it dies with an error on the login page.

Comment: where is your var_dump? is it another page

Comment: `session_start()` should be the very first line. even before the include

Comment: meda said it... and i believe you dont have error_reporting on too

Comment: @zod Yes it is on my main page. Where the user is getting sent to after a successfull login, as it says in my script.

Comment: you need session_start there too..or use in a common file and include it

Comment: Do you have any whitespace before the `<?php` tag? If so, you need to remove it first.

Comment: @neda While including login.php where session_start() already is started. I can't use session_start() twice, do i?
+ Yes on the main page where the user is getting sent to, the session has already started.

Comment: or put it right above `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;`

Comment: Turn on your error reporting. Make your session_start() call to the top of the page, check your variables are correctly assigned to the database prior to setting to session. Redirect to another page, re-start the session in invoking `session_start()` then var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: I was wrong, you were right. God bless humanity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first php script, move the session_start() above the include statement.
In your html file, add session_start(); above the include statement.